# How to identify all format properties in each cell VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get the format properties of each cell in column E. I have no issue to identify the properties if the text that is 
in each cell has a unique Font.Name, Font.Size, Font.ColorIndex and Font.FontStyle.

The issue I have is that in some cells there is text with one format and other text with another and in that case my current code it seems that is only printing
 the format of the first character.

for example in one cell is `abc def.`, where abc is Arial, 9, black, Regular and def is Calibri, 18, green, Bold:

How to identify all format properties in each cell?

My current code is below:

```
Sub GetFormat()
    For i = 1 To 8
        nName = Cells(i, "E").Font.Name
        sSize = Cells(i, "E").Font.Size
        cColor = Cells(i, "E").Font.ColorIndex
        sStyle = Range("E" & i).Font.FontStyle
        Cells(i, "A") = nName
        Cells(i, "B") = sSize
        Cells(i, "C") = cColor
        Cells(i, "D") = sStyle
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to loop over the `Characters` collection and check each one in turn

Comment: May you show an example please?

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to identify all formatting in order to analyse later if there is something to fix, for example, some cells that should have some font name or font color have other, then I need to change later accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop over each cell's `Characters` collection and check each character in turn.

For example:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim rng As Range, c, n As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1")

    For n = 1 To rng.Characters.Count
        With rng.Characters(n, 1)
            Debug.Print n, "Bold", .Font.Bold
            Debug.Print n, "Color", .Font.ColorIndex
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. It helped a lot your example. I was able to include the `Characters` evaluation in my code.